# How to prove this inequation?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

How to prove this inequation.
$$(\frac{n}{m})^m\le C_n^m\le(\frac{en}{m})^m$$
where $0<m\le n$ and $C_n^m$is the Combinatorial number.

I tried to prove the left part by using the convexity of $\ln$, but it can't work on the right part.

the proof of the left part:
$$
\ln(\frac{n}{m})^m=m(\ln n-\ln m) \\
\ln C_n^m=\ln n + \cdots+\ln (n-m+1)-\ln m - \cdots \ln 1=\sum_{i=1}^m(\ln (n+i-m)-\ln i)
$$
Due to the convexity of $\ln$ function:
$$\ln n-\ln m \le ln (n+i-m)-\ln i$$
so：
$$\ln(\frac{n}{m})^m \le \ln C_n^m$$

Comment: Your `m` cannot be equal to zero since division by zero is impossible. Also the notation `n,k` instead of `n,m` (which are similar) is preferable.

Comment: This looks like it's probably meant for mathematics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @N.J.Evans: Did you read my answer before you have submitted your comment?

Comment: Yes, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The second inequality can be verified as follows.

```
NMaximize[{Binomial[n, k]/(E*n/k)^k,k <= n && {n, k} \[Element] PositiveIntegers},{n, k}, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}]
```

> `{0.367879, {n -> 26964, k -> 1}}`

I leave the first inequality on your own.